# html5 and ie10 for windows 7 and windows 8

Tags: html

I've got a html5 site that displays fine in ie 10 for windows 7, but when I run it in ie10 for windows 8 it automatically switches to compatability view. The doc type in the html5 is :

```
<!doctype html>
<!--[if lt IE 7]> <html class="ie6 oldie"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7]>    <html class="ie7 oldie"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8]>    <html class="ie8 oldie"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if gt IE 8]><!-->
<html class="">
<!--<![endif]-->
<head>
```

I've made this site with dreamweaver.

Why thus this happens?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest going through these steps: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/hh779632.aspx

Especially run the Compatibility Inspector, located in the section titled: **Other reasons my page does not render correctly**

Comment: I've tried and tried again, and nothing.
Also checked with the "http://validator.w3.org/" for html5 compatibility and it passed without errors!!!
Don't know what to do.
The url is: http://www.widedreams.pt/_projectos/entreser/index.html
If someone please see what's making this IE annoying thing to happen, I'd be very grateful.
THanks

Comment: Also checked in http://www.modern.ie/, and no error ... yet the page always goes to compatibilty mode!

Comment: Now for something more odd: when previewing the site locally in IE10 W8 it works fine but after uploading the files and previewing remotelly in the same browser (IE10 W9) it doesn't makes the same error I've mentioned!

Comment: Is your site on the compatibility list? Go through it carefully to ensure the host isn't listed